# [Resolve]How can we get multiple value with different api react?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm building a personal widget for my cryptocurrencies and i wanted to know how i can call different values using the same variables but different function , already did the avax get coin which work alone , but when I'm trying to build for example the sand get coin nothing shown on the both price , if someone can help me to find out what I'm doing bad (im a beginner). Thanks !

```
const App = () => {
  const [ticker, setTicker] = useState({
    last: 0,
  });

  useEffect(()=> {
    async function getAvaxcoinPrice() {
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://nitinr-cors.herokuapp.com/https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/tickers/avaxusdt');
      setTicker(data.ticker);
    }
    getAvaxcoinPrice();
    setInterval(() => getAvaxcoinPrice(), 10000);
  }, []);

  useEffect(()=> {
    async function getSandcoinPrice() {
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://nitinr-cors.herokuapp.com/https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/tickers/sandusdt');
      setTicker(data.ticker);
    }
    getSandcoinPrice();
    setInterval(() => getSandcoinPrice(), 10000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className='avaxcontainer'>
      <h1 className='title'>AVAX</h1>
        <div className='prices-containerAV'>
            <PriceCardAV type="current" getAvaxcoinprice={ticker.last}/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='sandcontainer'>
      <h1 className='title'>SAND</h1>
        <div className='prices-containerSA'>
            <PriceCardSA type="current" getSandcoinprice={ticker.last}/>
        </div>
  );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store each currency as a key in the object and update the values of those keys.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pricefetch-557qsc